# Commerce Product using Display Suite

Tags: commerce

Im using Commerce for Drupal 8. When using Display Suite to create a two column display for Products, the Price and Attributes disappear. Is it possible to use Display Suite for Commerce Products to achieve a two column display?

Answer (score 0):

No. Display Suite is not compatible with Commerce Products.

Commerce issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2723689
Display suite issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2725077